# Unobtrusive Mode for jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Is there an unobtrusive mode for jQuery Mobile?

I'd like to use the styles and functionality of the lists, inputs, buttons, alerts, toolbars, etc. without it taking over the entire site. Similar to the way jQuery UI works - just pick components.

For example, when I add jQuery Mobile, it completely changes the way my page looks & works. The background is gone, the markup is restructured, links & forms become ajax, etc.

I tried disabling ajax (see code) but jQuery mobile still completely restructured & restyled my page.

```
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `data-role="none"` to the elements?
[Native form elements & buttons](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html)

Comment: data-role is intended for form elements - I'm talking about jQuery Mobile's restructuring of my entire page